# Using ADF to get a subset of files from the directory in Azure File Share

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

For example my Azure file share directory contains the following files:

```
abc_YYYYMMDD.txt
def_YYYYMMDD.txt
ijk_YYYYMMDD.txt
```

I'm only interested to get abc_YYYYMMDD.txt and ijk_YYYYMMDD.txt

Currently, I have a Get Metadata activity that gets a list of files (childItems property) inside a File Share directory.

Then I have Filter activity that has this dynamic content:

```
@startswith(item().name, variables('filename_filter')) OR startswith(item().name, 
variables('filename2filter')))
```

Unfortunately, it has an error:

```
Position 54 'startswith' is a primitive and doesn't support nested properties
```

How do I resolve this if I have multiple conditions inside the Dynamic Content for Filter activity?

Comment: It's very clear how you want filter the file, by prefix or surfix? The file name all have same format and YYYYMMDD is the data format, am I right?

Comment: sorry, it should be: @startswith(item().name, variables('filename_filter')) OR startswith(item().name, 
variables('filename2filter')))

filename_filter variable value has: abc_
filename2filter variable value has ijk_

Comment: Hi @kayeesp, it's all right. Do you mean it's resolved now? Usually, parameter and variable also should works.

Comment: Nope, i still have error 'startswith' is a primitive and doesn't support nested properties. Can we do a logical or for dynamic content? this seems not working if i have startswith in the expression.

Comment: Let me have a try and will update you.

Comment: Hi @kayeesp, please see my answer.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Filter expression should be like this:

```
@or(startswith(item().name,variables('filename_filter')),startswith(item().name,variables('filename2filter'))
```

The expression doesn't support "or" directly, you should use `or()` function.

This is my source folder:
[image]

I create a pipeline,  using parameters to filter the filename which start with "test1" and "test2":

[image]

Run the pipeline:
[image]

Output:
[image]

HTH.